# How to convert .csv format file to .tde format file (tableau extract) using Python?

Tags: python, csv, extract, tableau-api

Below are issues I am facing

I am not able to install `dataextract` package properly using below command and hence facing issues while importing the package.

```
"python -m pip install dada extract"
```

Also facing issues in the below command in `tableau_rest_api` package

```
 TableauRestApi(server, username, password)
```

Can any one tell me alternative way to perform same task or help me correct the existing code

```
    #######convert .csv file to .tde file#########################
import os,csv,datetime
import dataextract as tde
# INSERT EXCEPT CONDITION
# EXTRACT FILE AND OPEN .CSV
try:
    tdefile = tde.Extract('trial1.tde')
except:
    os.remove('trial1.tde')``
    tdefile = tde.Extract('trial1.tde')

csvReader= csv.reader(open('test1.csv','rb'),delimiter=',',quotechar='"')

# CREATE THE TABLE DEF
tableDef= tde.TableDefinition()
tableDef.addColumn('Country',tde.Type.CHAR_STRING)
tableDef.addColumn('sales',tde.Type.INTEGER)
tableDef.addColumn('units',tde.Type.INTEGER)

# CREATE TABLE
table=tdefile.addTable('C:\Users\Mahita.Gm\Desktop\Extract',tableDef)

# DATA TO TDE

newrow= tde.Row(tableDef)
csvReader.next()
for line in csvReader:
    newrow.setCharString(0,str(line[0]))
    newrow.setInteger(1,int(line[1]))
    newrow.setInteger(2,int(line[2]))
    table.insert(newrow)

# closing tde
tdefile.close()

#############code to publish tableau extract in to server #################
import tableau_rest_api
from tableau_rest_api.tableau_rest_api import * import urllib2
username = '<user name>'
password = '<password>'
server = '<server address>'
logger = Logger('publish.log')

test = TableauRestApi(server, username, password)
test.enable_logging(logger)
test.signin()

test_ds_proj_luid = test.query_project_luid_by_name('default')
#test_ds_wb_luid = test.query_workbook_luid_by_name('test_1_c_CF')

#test_ds_p_luid = test.query_datasource_luid_by_name_in_project('trial1', 'test_1_c_CF')
# Publishing up my first data source to Test, from disk
new_ds_luid = test.publish_datasource('trial1.tde', 'trial1', test_ds_proj_luid, overwrite=True)
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's two packages called `dada` and `extract`? This is painfully obvious typo to me. Also are you sure that `dataextract` is on pypi? Might you need to download the code and run the `setup.py`?

Comment: You need to reference the docs. The libraries you are trying to use make no sense. http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/sdk/en-us/help.htm#SDK/tableau_sdk_using_python.htm%3FTocPath%3D_____4